# SQL works in SQLite but doesn't work in php my admin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, incompatibility

I have some SQL:

`CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userneme TEXT, password TEXT); 
CREATE TABLE userinfo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_id INTEGER, email TEXT, year_joined INTEGER, month_joined INTEGER, day_joined INTEGER); 
CREATE TABLE stories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type INTEGER, users INTEGER, genre TEXT);`

this code works great on khan academy (which uses SQLite), but php my admin says

> Error
>   SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userneme TEXT, password TEXT);
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds >to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTOINCREMENT, userneme TEXT, password TEXT)' at line 1
>
> Open new phpMyAdmin window

does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Well, SQL syntax is not equal across all platforms. Most likely MySQL doesn't like `AUTOINCREMENT`, you will have to change the SQL to work with MySQL.

Comment: it's auto_increment in mysql

Comment: You basically need to specify size for integer column. As shared in the answer by Asraful.

Comment: Also column names like `password` are keywords, so prefer creating a query adding column names in backtick. also datatype TEXT is huge for fields like `usename` and `password` try using `varchar` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code brother.

---

```
CREATE TABLE users (id integer(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, userneme TEXT, password TEXT); 
CREATE TABLE userinfo (id integer(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id integer(11), email TEXT, year_joined integer(11), month_joined integer(11), day_joined integer(11)); 
CREATE TABLE stories (id integer(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT, type integer(11), users integer(11), genre TEXT)
```